# Go Mongo Update NonZero values only

Tags: mongodb, go, go-modules, mongo-go

How to update the document with non zero values only. As example I didn't received any value for status and Struct has only two values to be updated. So it should only update those 2 values and skip zero/null values. But as given below it's updating it to zero/null/""

```
type Product struct {
    ID          primitive.ObjectID `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    Status      int                `json:"status" bson:"status"`
    DisplayName string             `json:"displayName" bson:"display_name"`
    Text        string             `json:"text" bson:"text"`
}
```

I have tried the following up it's overriding the status value to 0 if no value is passed for it.

```
    opts := options.Update().SetUpsert(false)

    filter := bson.D{primitive.E{Key: "_id", Value: product.ID}}
    update := bson.D{{"$set", bson.D{{"status", product.Status}, bson.D{{"text",product.Text}, {"display_name", product.DisplayName}}}}
    _, err := db.Collection("product").UpdateOne(context.TODO(), filter, update, opts)
```

How to achieve this cleanly without ifs. For any struct in Service.

Answer (score 3):

First, your `update` document should not contain an embedded document if `Product` is the Go struct that models your documents. It should be:

```
update := bson.D{
    {"$set", bson.D{
        {"status", product.Status},
        {"text", product.Text},
        {"display_name", product.DisplayName},
    }},
}
```

Now on to your issue. You explicitly tell in the `update` document to set them to their zero value, so that's what MongoDB does.

If you don't want to set zero values, don't add them to the update document. Build your `update` document like this:

```
setDoc := bson.D{}
if product.Status != 0 {
    setDoc = append(setDoc, bson.E{"status", product.Status})
}
if product.Text != "" {
    setDoc = append(setDoc, bson.E{"text", product.Text})
}
if product.DisplayName != "" {
    setDoc = append(setDoc, bson.E{"display_name", product.DisplayName})
}

update := bson.D{{"$set", setDoc}}
```

Note that you can achieve the same if you use the `,omitempty` BSON tag option and use / pass a `Product` struct value for the `setDoc`:

```
type Product struct {
    ID          primitive.ObjectID `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    Status      int                `json:"status" bson:"status,omitempty"`
    DisplayName string             `json:"displayName" bson:"display_name,omitempty"`
    Text        string             `json:"text" bson:"text,omitempty"`
}
```

And then simply:

```
update := bson.D{{"$set", product}}
```

Comment: So there no clean way to do it, I mean without ifs? 
Because Product is not only struct/document in service. So is there is way to do it generically?

Comment: @ZaynKorai You can do it in a "clean" way if you use `,omitempty` and a `Product` value for the `setDoc`. See edited answer. But be sure to use consistent `bson` tag names, ones that match fields in your MongoDB (the ones you posted in the question seems off).

Comment: Updated the question, I wrote Product struct just for the question so made a mistake their. It's fixed now.

Comment: @ZaynKorai OK, then using the struct with `,omitempty` is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

I created my own solution

```golang
// CreateUpdateQuery creates a query for updating a model, partially picks fields from the model.
// It also skips fields with zero values.
func CreateUpdateQuery[T any](model *T) bson.M {
    updateQuery := bson.M{}
    v := reflect.ValueOf(model).Elem()
    t := v.Type()

    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        var (
            name  string
            field = t.Field(i)
            tag   = field.Tag.Get("bson")
        )

        if tag == "" {
            tag = field.Tag.Get("json")
        }

        if tag == "" {
            name = field.Name
        } else {
            // Exclude "omitempty" from the tag
            parts := strings.Split(tag, ",")
            if len(parts) > 0 {
                name = parts[0]
            } else {
                name = field.Name
            }
        }

        if name != "" && !IsZeroOfUnderlyingType(v.Field(i).Interface()) {
            updateQuery[name] = v.Field(i).Interface()
        }
    }

    return updateQuery
}


// IsZeroOfUnderlyingType returns true if the value is the zero value for its type.
func IsZeroOfUnderlyingType(x any) bool {
    if x == nil {
        return true
    }
    return reflect.DeepEqual(x, reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf(x)).Interface())
}
```

then i use it like this

```golang
// .... p is params 
filter := bson.M{"id": p.ID}
update := bson.M{"$set": CreateUpdateQuery(p)}
_, err := s.collection.UpdateOne(ctx, filter, update)
```